# Creating iPhone styled tabs

Tags: android, iphone, tabs

Before I get flak for trying to create iPhone style elements on Android, it is my internship assignment to convert an iPhone app to an Android app while preserving the look and feel as good as possible.

So far, everything is going well, but I've run into a problem. The app is using several tab-bars. At least, that's what I call them.
And I have absolutely no idea how to make these on Android. I know you can create tab bars with big clunky buttons, but I haven't really seen any apps that use tabs as shown here:

[image: I would like tabs like this]

Is there any way to achieve this on Android? Like I said, I haven't seen anyone do it before so I'm not quite sure if it's even possible.
Any pointers are appreciated.

---

**Edit:** I just found this: http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/
I think I can achieve what I want pretty accurately with this, but I would like to know if anyone else has any pointers as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can customize the TabHost and the tab items as you wish though it's kinda different from Apple counterpart.
Android uses 9-patch image as default for the tab bar background and that's why you also need to use that to make it proper.

Check this for some lead about it.

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Answer (score 2):

How about [android-segment](https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton) library?

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want, but by the looks of it, the look (and therefore the colors) are determined by the 9-patch files you use. I would love it if we could easily change the colors of the buttons by just putting in a different color, but I suppose that's a bit too much to ask for. However this does look great so I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The way i have done it is using 3 draw nine's one for the left right and middle. pressed states as well. Then just using regular buttons to draw them in a linearlayout with all of them having equal weight.

Depending on your usage using tab style loading with new fragments or activities would be the way to go or simply having a onClick that switches the data being loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this one. It has a bottom tabs, but the look and feel of tabs are like i-phone style.

http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2011/12/i-phone-style-tabbar-in-android.html#more